# Regex parse exception in android

Tags: android

I am trying to validate my password field.
This is my regex :- `"^[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%^&_+=]{,}$"`
It was working fine earlier but now i don't know why it is throwing error

Error in {min,max} interval near index 23:
    ^[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%^&_+=]{,}$
    ^

Please kindly help

Comment: Try This:-- ^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{4,}$

Comment: I want a regex which may contain special characters or numbers. This regex is for mandatory one special character, one upper case and so on

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844359/password-regex-with-min-6-chars-at-least-one-letter-and-one-number-and-may-cont